# erlang inter-process lock mechanism (such as flock)

Tags: erlang, flock, interprocess

Does Erlang have an inter-process (I mean Linux or Windows process) lock mechanism such as flock ?

The usage would be as follows :

- an Erlang server starts serving a repository, and puts a file lock (or whatever)
- if another OS process (another Erlang server or a command-line Erlang script) interacts with the repo, then the file lock warns about possible conflict

Answer (score 5):

If you mean between Erlang processes, no, it has inter-process lock mechanisms. That is not the Erlang way of controlling access to a shared resource. Generally if you want to control access to a resource you have an Erlang process which manages the resource and all access to the resource goes through this process. This means we have no need for inter-process locks or mutexes to control access. It is also safe as you can't "cheat" and access anyway and the managing process can detect if clients die in the middle of a transaction.

Comment: I meant OS Processes. I'm going to update my question and add this detail.

Answer (score 1):

In Erlang, you would probably use a different way of solving this. One thing that comes to mind is to keep a single Erlang `node()` which handles all the repositories. It has a `lock_mgr` process which does the resource lock management.

When another node or escript wants to run, it can connect to the running Erlang node over distribution and request the locking.

Answer (score 0):

There is module `global` which could fit your needs.

`global:set_lock/1,2,3`

> Sets a lock on the specified nodes (or on all nodes if none are specified) on ResourceId for LockRequesterId.